# Black border outside the embedded Gists?

Tags: css

The embedded Gists on my [blog](http://wlhunag.blogspot.tw/2015/04/goldendict.html) have a black border outside the scripts.
[image]

I had inspected the elements through developer tools , but found nothing about the black border.

How can I get gid off this black border?

Comment: Can you provide your site URL?

Comment: I had update my posts (I forgot to include the link)

Comment: you have `td {
padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
border: solid 1px black;
}` on your page which is causing that

Comment: @Mr. Alien its right. Then, removing border of `.line-data` will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table cells have a border in the `<style>` section of the page (line 203)

```
td {
  padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
  border: solid 1px black; /* remove this */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have borders on `<td>` somewhere in the CSS, try the following to rest it for Gists.

```
.gist .line-numbers,
.gist .line-data {
    border: 0;
}
```